# Spark Streaming with schema-less data

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams

We currently have a data pipeline setup where we are reading raw data from a single Kafka topic using Logstash and write it to ElasticSearch.
The data in this topic is in JSON format, but each row can belong to a completely different business domain, so it may have completely different schema. For example:

record 1: "{"id":1,"model":"model2","updated":"2017-01-1T00:00:00.000Z","domain":"A"}

record 2: "{"id":"some_compound_key","result":"PASS","domain":"B"}

You can see that not only is the schema different, but it is actually conflicting (id is an integer in the first record, and a string in the second).

There are only two guarantees - each record is a valid JSON record, and each has a "domain" field. Even records with the same domain value can sometimes have different schemas.

We now have a requirement to enrich and transform this data as it goes through the pipeline (instead of doing it later with an ETL), and we're looking into several ways of accomplishing it. The caveat is that since the data has no unified schema, the transformation needs to be done on a row by row basis:

1) Continue using Logstash - it is possible to model the transformation pipeline that we need, per domain, using a set of Logstash filters and conditionals.
It is also easy to maintain and deploy since Logstash reloads the configuration periodically in runtime, so to change/add transformation logic we only need to drop a new config file in the conf directory.
The downside however is that it is very hard to enrich data with Logstash from external sources.

2) Use Kafka Streams - This seems like an obvious choice since it integrates well with Kafka, allows joining data from multiple streams (or external sources) and has no schema requirements - it is easy to transform the data row by row.
Here the downside is that it is difficult to modify the transformation logic in runtime - we need to either recompile and redeploy the app, or wrap it with some API that would generate and compile Java code in runtime, or some other complex solution.

3) Use Spark Streaming - we are already using Spark for batch processing, so it would be great if we could use it for streaming as well to keep our stack as simple as possible.
However, I'm not sure if Spark can even support streaming data that doesn't have a single schema, nor if it's possible to perform transformations on a per-row basis.
All of the examples I've seen (as well as our own experience with Spark batch processing) assume that the data has a well defined schema, which is not our use case.

Can anyone shed some light on whether what we need is possible with Spark Streaming (or Structured Streaming), or should we stick with Logstash / Kafka Streams?

Answer (score 1):

> *Disclaimer: I am an active contributor to Kafka Streams.*

I am not familiar with Logstash, but from what you did describe, it seems to be the least attractive solution.

About Spark Streaming. Even if I am not a big fan of it, I believe you could do the processing you want to do with it. Structured Streaming would not work from my understanding, as it requires a fixed schema, but Spark Streaming should be more flexible. However, using Spark Streaming would not make it simpler compared to Kafka Streams (but most likely harder). I have no personal experience with running Spark Streaming in production, but I heard many complaints about instability etc.

About the "disadvantages" of Kafka Streams you pointed out. (1) I am not sure why you need code generation etc. and (2), why would this be any different in Spark Streaming? You need to write your transformation logic in both cases and if you wanna change it you need to redeploy. I also believe, that updating a Kafka Streams application via "rolling bounces" is way easier and allows for zero down time compared to Spark Streaming for which you need to stop processing in between.

It would be helpful to understand what "code modification at runtime" you want to do in order to give a more detailed answer here.

Comment: There is no difference between Kafka Streams and Spark Streaming in terms of manageability - both would require recompiling the application and redeploying it - which is something we'd like to avoid if possible and find a way to support adding new lambda functions in runtime, for example.

I agree that Kafka Streams is more flexible - since each streaming application is standalone, we can easily scale them up/down by adding more containerized instances, which we cannot do as easily with Spark.
You also make a good point in regards to rolling bounces - I haven't considered it :-)

Thanks!

Comment: "Schema is required for spark structured streaming" is arguable. We have pipelines deployed on prod that are completely agnostic to schema.

Comment: @TroubleShooter How do you implement that?

Comment: @VictorKironde, if you can remove the need to deserialize payloads (note that you can examine any fields within the payload using JSON libraries) any spark pipeline can be made schema agnostic. For JSON, we use io.gatling.jsonpath to lookup specific fields within a message, which is enough from Spark's standpoint.